# Unable to read memory error comes up every time I use the function below,

Tags: c, visual-studio

I tried to write a function similar to sscanf that forwards the input string pointer, so it could be used like scanf to scan multiple strings one after the other. when I tried to use the function
there was an exception so I ran it in debug and it is unable to read the input Strings value.

```
 int scanStrAndMove(char **readString, char* formatString, char * writeString){
      int forwardBy = 0;
      while(isspace(*readString[forwardBy])){
          forwardBy++;
      }
      int retVal = sscanf(*readString,formatString,writeString);
      forwardBy += strlen(writeString) + strlen(formatString) - 2;
      if(retVal > 0) *readString += forwardBy;
      return retVal;
}
```

[a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTY2w.png)

[the calling of the function(line is of type char*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YEi6.png)

edit: I tried to replace *readString with another char* to and it didn't solve the problem, thanks for all the answers.

edit: I saw the comments and tried to make a minimal reproducible example, try to run this with the function above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char inputStr[10] = "  cde fg";
  char outputSrt[10];
  scanStrAndMove(&inputStr,"%s",outputSrt);
  printf("%s",outputSrt);
  scanStrAndMove(&inputStr,"%s",outputSrt);
  printf("%s",outputSrt)
   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you call that function and how to you create the paremeters you pass?

Comment: `isspace(*readString[forwardBy])` ... do you mean `readString[0][forwardBy]` or `readString[forwardBy][0]`? If in doubt ... use parentheses: `isspace((*readString)[forwardBy])` or `isspace(*(readString[forwardBy]))` ... or the array syntax :-)

Comment: I am calling it in the main function. I'm passing the address of a string and two other strings

Comment: Read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence and figure out what happens when you do: `*p[i]` Is it `*(p[i])` or is it `(*p)[i]`

Comment: OT: Your code would IMO be much simpler (and at least one error would go away) if you started by doing: `char* rsP = *readString;` and replaced `*readString` by `rsP` where it's not an assignment.

Comment: Hmm, `int scanStrAndMove(char **readString, ...)` called as `scanStrAndMove(&line, ...)` is likely to be the error. But without knowing how `line` is declared in main, I can neither be sure nor propose a fix. Had you given a [mre], you would have got an answer...

Comment: From your screenshot we still can't see what `line` is....